# How to access Notification Accessibility page via intent?

Tags: java, android, android-permissions, accessibility

I am building an Android Application that needs the Notification Accessibility permission.
My thought is to take the user to the Notification Accessibility page when the app is first started, How can I do this via intent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To open NotificationAccessSettingsActivity via intent you could do something like this:

```
startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS));
```

If you want to check the permission you could use:

```
private boolean isNotificationServiceRunning() {
ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
String enabledNotificationListeners =
        Settings.Secure.getString(contentResolver, "enabled_notification_listeners");
String packageName = getPackageName();
return enabledNotificationListeners != null && enabledNotificationListeners.contains(packageName);
```

}